# HTML wireframe toolbox

Tags: html, css, wireframe

I've been using [Dreamweaver](http://www.boxesandarrows.com/view/dreamweaver_primer) to create my wireframes (tables).

Before I create my own css/html/icon framework I would like know if such a library already exists.

The ideal toolbox would include basic styles for all `form elements`, `icons`, `css grid layout`, `sample standard ad sizes`, and `empty templates`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, these all exist only separately. There are a few [notable CSS frameworks](http://speckyboy.com/2008/03/28/top-12-css-frameworks-and-how-to-understand-them/), some with grid layouts, and [CSS form styling](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/11/11/css-based-forms-modern-solutions/) is almost a separate discipline. As for [web icons](http://www.google.co.uk/images?hl=en&rlz=&q=web+icons&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=univ&ei=pctSTMK0NNG6jAfPko3DBA&sa=X&oi=image_result_group&ct=title&resnum=1&ved=0CDgQsAQwAA&biw=1487&bih=848), take your pick!

The only place you're likely to find these all together (including plug-ins/add-ons) is in a full-blown [web framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks) or [CMS](http://www.cmsmatrix.org/).

If you put such a package together for yourself, bear in mind that it will be useful to many others, make sure the HTML ad CSS validates, and [choose css-based templates](http://www.dreamweaver-templates.org/css-resources.htm) rather than table-based ones...